# Support for Hive, Sqoop & Pig

Tags: apache, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

1. Does Apache Atlas support the tags for Spark, Pig, and Sqoop?

   - If Atlas support Pig, Sqoop & Spark then is there any kind of customization
     that we have to perform to make it work Atlas.
   - From where we can gets the exact process if we want to implement the above
     Hadoop components with Atlas.
2. Where does Atlas store the metadata?

   - How we can reach the schema of Atlas metadata.
3. Does Atlas provide the feature to fetch metadata for other tools (e.g.
   Informatica) and integrate it with its own metadata?

   - If Atlas support the above feature then how we can integrate the informatica
     with Atlas metadata.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** 
The list of bridges can be found at http://atlas.apache.org/index.html

At the time of answering, there are only bridges for hive, sqoop, falcon and storm.

To add Spark and Pig support, there are two options:

- Either use the Atlas Rest API(http://atlas.apache.org/api/v2/index.html) and trigger it in your code
- Implement our own bridge (https://github.com/apache/incubator-atlas/tree/master/addons)

**Question 2:** 
quoting http://atlas.apache.org/Architecture.html

> Titan: Currently, Atlas uses the Titan Graph Database to store the
>   metadata objects. Titan is used as a library within Atlas. Titan uses
>   two stores: The Metadata store is configured to !HBase by default and
>   the Index store is configured to Solr. It is also possible to use the
>   Metadata store as BerkeleyDB and Index store as ElasticSearch by
>   building with corresponding profiles. The Metadata store is used for
>   storing the metadata objects proper, and the Index store is used for
>   storing indices of the Metadata properties, that allows efficient
>   search.

**Question 3:** 
See question 1, it would not be any different from an implementation for Spark or Pig.

Answer (score 0):

Apache atlas support hive. Please check the below link

http://atlas.incubator.apache.org/Bridge-Hive.html

I hope this will help you. Not sure about your second and third question.

Comment: Hive : http://atlas.incubator.apache.org/Bridge-Hive.html
Limitations
• Since database name, table name and column names are case insensitive in hive, the corresponding names in entities are lowercase. So, any search APIs should use lowercase while querying on the entity names
• Only the following hive operations are captured by hive hook currently - create database, create table, create view, CTAS, load, import, export, query, alter table rename and alter view rename

Comment: Looking forward if any one knows how informatica can integrate with atlas meta data....

Comment: As per apache atlas developer "Apache atlas supports integration with hive. limited integration with storm, kafka, sqoop and falcon is available in 0.6
Atlas metadata is stored in titan graph.Atlas doesn’t support metadata exchange with informatica currently. Its in the roadmap." Hope this will be useful for you.